# How to browse and to display XML content with Java

Tags: java, html, xml, dom, sax

I have a problem in Java with DOM...
Here is the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bib>
<domain>
    <title>Specifications</title>
    <bib_ref>
        <year>March 2000</year>
        <title>MOF  1.3</title>
        <author>OMG</author>
        <weblink>D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\MOF1_3.pdf</weblink>
    </bib_ref>
    <bib_ref>
        <year>August 2002</year>
        <title>IDLto Java LanguageMapping Specification</title>
        <author>OMG</author>
        <weblink>D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\IDL2Java.pdf</weblink>
    </bib_ref>
    <bib_ref>
        <year>1999</year>
        <title>XML Metadata Interchange (XMI) Version 1.1</title>
        <author>OMG</author>
        <weblink>D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\xmi-1.1.pdf</weblink>
    </bib_ref>
    <bib_ref>
        <year>2002</year>
        <title>XML Metadata Interchange (XMI) Version 2</title>
        <author>"OMG</author>
        <weblink>D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\XMI2.pdf</weblink>
    </bib_ref>
    <bib_ref>
        <year>2002</year>
        <title>XMI Version 1Production of XML Schema Specification</title>
        <author>OMG</author>
        <weblink>D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\XMI1XSD.pdf</weblink>
    </bib_ref>
    <bib_ref>
        <year>2002</year>
        <title>EDOC</title>
        <author>OMG</author>
        <weblink>D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\EDOC02-02-05.pdf</weblink>
    </bib_ref>
</domain>
<domain>
    <title>Theses</title>
    <bib_ref>
        <year>Octobre 2001</year>
        <title>Echanges de Spécifications Hétérogènes et Réparties</title>
        <author>Xavier Blanc</author>
        <weblink>D:\SALIM\Docs\Theses\TheseXavier.pdf</weblink>
    </bib_ref>
    <bib_ref>
        <year>Janvier 2001</year>
        <title>Composition of Object-Oriented Software Design Models</title>
        <author>Siobhan Clarke</author>
        <weblink>D:\SALIM\Docs\Theses\SClarkeThesis.pdf</weblink>
    </bib_ref>
 ......
 ......
```

After, in Java main function, I call the dispContent function which is just there:

```
public void dispContent (Node n) 
{
    
    String domainName = null;
    
    // we are in an element node
    if (n instanceof Element) {
        Element e = ((Element) n);
       
        // domain title
        if (e.getTagName().equals("title") && e.getParentNode().getNodeName().equals("domain")) {
            domainName = e.getTextContent();
            DomaineTemplate(domainName);
        }
        
        else if (e.getTagName().equals("bib_ref")) {
            NodeList ref = e.getChildNodes();

            for (int i = 0; i < ref.getLength(); i++) {
                Node temp = (Node) ref.item(i);
                
                if (temp.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    if (temp.getNodeType() == org.w3c.dom.Node.TEXT_NODE)
                        continue;
                
                    out.println(temp.getNodeName() + " : " + temp.getTextContent() + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        
        else {
            NodeList sub = n.getChildNodes();
            for(int i=0; (i < sub.getLength()); i++)
                dispContent(sub.item(i));

        }
    }
        /*else if (n instanceof Document) {
        NodeList fils = n.getChildNodes();
        for(int i=0; (i < fils.getLength()); i++) {
            dispContent(fils.item(i));
    
        }
    }*/
}
```

The "domaineTemplate" function just displays its parameter!
My problem happens when I browse the "bib_ref" tag in Java. For each "bib_ref" loop, it displays all the contents of all "bib_ref" tags... in one line! I want to display only one content (year, title, author and weblink tag) per "bib_ref".

Here is what it is displaying at the moment when I browse bib_ref :

> Specifications
>
> year : March 2000 title : MOF 1.3 author : OMG weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\MOF1_3.pdf year : August 2002 title : IDLto Java LanguageMapping Specification author : OMG weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\IDL2Java.pdf year : 1999 title : XML Metadata Interchange (XMI) Version 1.1 author : OMG weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\xmi-1.1.pdf year : 2002 title : XML Metadata Interchange (XMI) Version 2 author : OMG weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\XMI2.pdf year : 2002 title : XMI Version 1Production of XML Schema Specification author : OMG weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\XMI1XSD.pdf year : 2002 title : EDOC author : OMG weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\EDOC02-02-05.pdf
>
> Theses
>
> year : Octobre 2001 title : Echanges de Sp�cifications H�t�rog�nes et R�parties author : Xavier Blanc weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Theses\TheseXavier.pdf year : Janvier 2001 title : Composition of Object-Oriented Software Design Models author : Siobhan Clarke weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Theses\SClarkeThesis.pdf year : Juin 2002 title : Contribution � la repr�sentation de processu par des techniques de m�ta mod�lisation author : Erwan Breton weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Theses\ErwanBretonThesis.pdf year : Octobre 2000 title : Technique de Mod�lisation et de M�ta mod�lisation author : Richard Lemesle weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Theses\RichardLemesle.pdf year : Juillet 2002 title : Utilsation d'agents mobiles pour la construction des services distribu�s author : Siegfried Rouvrais weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Theses\theserouvrais.pdf
> ...
> ...

Can you help me ?
I'm just a beginner in xml with java and I'm searching some solution for about 3 hours... Thank's a lot!

Comment: Refering to this line out.println(temp.getNodeName() + " : " + temp.getTextContent() + "\n"); What is out? How is println defined? Have you tried \r\n instead of just \n? And I'm also curious about the DomaineTemplate(domainName); consturct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I called `dispContent(doc.getFirstChild());` where doc is the Document with your given xml file contents.

Assumptions: `out.println()` is `System.out.println()` and `DomaineTemplate(domainName);` adds a newline (based on your output provided)

I get the following print out in the console:

```
Specifications

year : March 2000

title : MOF  1.3

author : OMG

weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\MOF1_3.pdf

year : August 2002

title : IDLto Java LanguageMapping Specification

author : OMG

weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\IDL2Java.pdf

year : 1999

title : XML Metadata Interchange (XMI) Version 1.1

author : OMG

weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\xmi-1.1.pdf

year : 2002

title : XML Metadata Interchange (XMI) Version 2

author : "OMG

weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\XMI2.pdf

year : 2002

title : XMI Version 1Production of XML Schema Specification

author : OMG

weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\XMI1XSD.pdf

year : 2002

title : EDOC

author : OMG

weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\EDOC02-02-05.pdf

Theses

year : Octobre 2001

title : Echanges de Spécifications Hétérogènes et Réparties

author : Xavier Blanc

weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Theses\TheseXavier.pdf

year : Janvier 2001

title : Composition of Object-Oriented Software Design Models

author : Siobhan Clarke

weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Theses\SClarkeThesis.pdf
```

If you're having an issue with `"\n"` creating a new line, you can try using what the System uses:

```
public static final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

If you don't want the new lines between each line of the "bib_ref" node's children print outs, change:

```
else if (e.getTagName().equals("bib_ref")) {
    NodeList ref = e.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < ref.getLength(); i++) {
            Node temp = (Node) ref.item(i);

            if (temp.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                if (temp.getNodeType() == org.w3c.dom.Node.TEXT_NODE)
                    continue;

                 out.println(temp.getNodeName() + " : " + temp.getTextContent() + "\n");
            }
        }
}
```

to:

```
else if (e.getTagName().equals("bib_ref")) {
    NodeList ref = e.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < ref.getLength(); i++) {
            Node temp = (Node) ref.item(i);

            if (temp.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                if (temp.getNodeType() == org.w3c.dom.Node.TEXT_NODE)
                    continue;

                 // Removed "\n":
                 out.println(temp.getNodeName() + " : " + temp.getTextContent());
            }
        }

        // Added out.println();
        out.println();
}
```

Results:

```
Specifications

year : March 2000
title : MOF  1.3
author : OMG
weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\MOF1_3.pdf

year : August 2002
title : IDLto Java LanguageMapping Specification
author : OMG
weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\IDL2Java.pdf

year : 1999
title : XML Metadata Interchange (XMI) Version 1.1
author : OMG
weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\xmi-1.1.pdf

year : 2002
title : XML Metadata Interchange (XMI) Version 2
author : "OMG
weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\XMI2.pdf

year : 2002
title : XMI Version 1Production of XML Schema Specification
author : OMG
weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\XMI1XSD.pdf

year : 2002
title : EDOC
author : OMG
weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Specifications\EDOC02-02-05.pdf

Theses

year : Octobre 2001
title : Echanges de Spécifications Hétérogènes et Réparties 
author : Xavier Blanc
weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Theses\TheseXavier.pdf

year : Janvier 2001
title : Composition of Object-Oriented Software Design Models
author : Siobhan Clarke
weblink : D:\SALIM\Docs\Theses\SClarkeThesis.pdf
```

Comment: I m going to try and I come back here. A big thanks to you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, now I see you have tagged your question with html and your code has nothing to do with html so far. So I asume out.println is some OutputStream for a Servlet and you're trying to Output html.

So the println linebreak, and the "\n" linebreaks are just available in the html sourcecode. The browser will skip this.

Change this line

> out.println(temp.getNodeName() + " : " + temp.getTextContent() +
>   "\n");

to

> out.println(temp.getNodeName() + " : " + temp.getTextContent() + "< br
>   />");

and a servlet should output just fine with the linebreaks.

Comment: A big big thank to you guys ! It works ! The problem was solved by your replacing code in the first reply and with the <br />. Effectively, it is not a servlet but a desktop application which has to generate html output as you said. I forgot to notice you of this fact, sorry! Thank's a lot.